# What is a 'Helpful Flag'?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I was looking in my profile, and I saw the 'Helpful Flag' thing with a number beside of it. I know it's not the number of upvoted questions or answers, because my number for both of these are higher. Are these the number of upvotes on comments that I have recieved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you see a question or answer, you may notice a row of buttons under the answer/questions content. Most commonly you see **Edit** and **Flag**

When you press flag, it gives you some options for why the question or answer requires a moderators attention. You choose one, and submit.

If your flag is valid and there was a problem, a moderator will mark it as **Helpful**. If not, it will be **declined**. Your profile contains the total number of helpful flags (only visible to you and mods). Clicking the number will show you everything you flagged, along with some stats on how many were helpful, or not.

Comment: I have only ever used the flag button once, though, and when I click on the number I only see the one time I actually used it

Comment: @ekaj If that number in your profile is 0 or 1, it's consistent with your flags. Flags haven't always been categorized this way (so even a useful flag that was acted on might not be marked *helpful*), and moderators can decide to *decline* your flag if it's not helpful.

Comment: @ekaj seems you've flagged few comments

Comment: @DanielBeck I have 13 "Helpful Flags" and I have only ever flagged one question.

Comment: @ekaj Sathya also just indicated that you had flagged a few comments. Look to the **right side** of the flag summary page, it should show some stats there